# .htaccess: Forward ALL requests to another site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, forward

I have to forward an existing website to another one.

I want to forward **each and every** request on the old site to the root of the new site.

Example:
`http://oldsite.tld/index.php?mode=foo&action=bar` should be forwarded to `http://newsite.tld/` and **not** `http://newsite.tld/index.php?mode=foo&action=bar`.

Is this possible with .htaccess alone? I'd also have the possibility of using PHP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I decided to do it with mod_rewrite, a simple `Redirect` in the *.htaccess* didn't quite do the job.

Here's what I ended up using:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://newsite.tld/? [R=301,L]
```

The `?` at the end of the URL makes sure all queries are ignored.

Answer (score -1):

Simply on the top of every file put

```
<?php
    header('Location: http://newsite.tld');
?>
```

Run a quick prepend operation on all `.php` files.

Comment: Is this the only way? I was hoping for a more "elegant" approach, but if that's the only way, I'll do it. Thanks.

Comment: No, you could also add a `.htaccess` redirect, but I'm not sure of the exact syntax on that and didn't want to look it up at 6:20 AM.